# How to ask user input only when branch matches master in Jenkinsfile pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I tried to use the following Jenkinsfile to ask input only on master branch and can't get the groovy grammer pass validation:

```
pipeline {
    stage('Deploy') {
        when {
            branch 'master'
        }

        steps {
            input(message: "Please input", parameters: [string(name: "VERSION", defaultValue="", description="")]
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [{name=VERSION, description=""}, null]
```

I searched a lot but didn't find a single one example about using `input` step in the Jenkinsfile with `parameters`.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find a way to do this, we should wrap the input with the `script` keyword.

```
    stage('Deploy to k8s prod') {
        when {
            branch 'release-prod'
        }

        steps {
            script {
                env.VERSION = input message: '请输入参数', ok: '确定', parameters: [
                string(name:'VERSION', description: "版本号")]
            }

            sh "echo ${env.VERSION}"
            }
        }
    }
```